# GraphHopper favored heading with CH enabled

Tags: java, android, graphhopper

I have a problem with GraphHopper 0.7.0 on Android. 
When I try to add point (start point of route) with favored heading using CH (fastest) prepared graph, I get:

```
 Error:[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Flexible mode not enabled on the server-side]
```

My request setting is:

```
request.setAlgorithm(Parameters.Algorithms.DIJKSTRA_BI);
request.getHints().put("instructions", "true");
request.getHints().put(Parameters.CH.DISABLE, true); 
request.setWeighting("fastest");
request.setVehicle("car");
```

I added this to config.properties before creating graph:

```
routing.maxVisitedNodes=1000000
routing.ch.disabling_allowed=true
```

I load graph this way:

```
GraphHopper tmpHopp = new GraphHopper().forMobile();
tmpHopp.load(new File(mapsFolder, currentArea+"-gh").getAbsolutePath());
```

I have checked this boolean after graph loadining:

tmpHopp.getCHFactoryDecorator().isDisablingAllowed() is false

and after route response:

resp.getHints().getBool(Parameters.CH.DISABLE, false) also returns false.

So it seems that my settings from config.properties and from hints are not applied.
When I don't use heading everything is working.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to disable CH (which is required for heading support) the graph needs to support disabling this and should return true for `tmpHopp.getCHFactoryDecorator().isDisablingAllowed()` (or just set this to true).

Comment: Thank you, calling getCHFactoryDecorator().setDisablingAllowed(true); solved problem, but shouldn't setting routing.ch.disabling_allowed=true be enought?

Comment: If you set this in the config.properties on your desktop how should the mobile app know about this? We currently do not store this into the graph ... should we?

Comment: hmm, so what options from config.properties are stored in the graph files?